# Using .get() and .find()/.filter() to show only a specific div from a html page search result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

I have a search bar on a page (/Search), & when the user searches for something, it will run a filter on the input text and refresh the page with the filtered results.

If someone searched the word "banana", the URL of the search results will be

> /Search?searchBoxText=banana

I'm trying to make that happen without refreshing the page.

In site.js is:

```
$(function () { 
    $("#searchBox").keyup(function (e) {
        var searchBoxText= $("#searchBox").val();
        $.get("/Search?searchBoxText=" + searchBoxText, function (getHtml) {
            $("#resultsDiv").html(getHtml);
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is that it displays the whole body of the page in `#resultsDiv` and I want it to just display `#resultsDiv`. So it displays the header, search bar & button again.

Essentially I want to display the new results (which would be in `#resultsDiv`) in the old `#resultsDiv` but I can't seem to constrain the .get() to only get a specific element from the resulting page.

I tried to do

- `$.get("/Search?searchBoxText=" + searchBoxText + " #resultsDiv", function (getHtml)`
- `$("#resultsDiv").html(getHtml).find("#resultsDiv");`

And other alterations like that but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Do you have any errors displaying in the browser console?

Comment: I get a "404 (Not Found)" but I'm pretty sure that it's not related to this issue. The code works, it gets the html page and displays it, it just displays all of it and I want to display just 1 div from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("#resultsDiv").html($(getHtml).find("#resultsDiv").html());
```

However, this is not the best way. Your call to `/Search?` should return only the HTML code of the page section that you want to update. This should be done server-side (you didn't say how you are returning the result, so I cannot help you about that).

Comment: Wow it was that simple. I didn't try to add another .html() at the end there. Thanks!